What are the steps in establishing a new lawn?
First time home owner and I've killed my lawn completely because of weeds and unevenness. I'm looking too see if I have the steps correct.

Rototill lawn
Add topsoil to smooth unevenness
Aerate lawn
Throw seeds and water


Tilling without first killing weeds, will just spread seeds/roots around.  Type of weeds and your growing location will matter also.  There are chemical(vinegar about the safest) and non chemical barriers(heavy black plastic) to kill weeds.  If you can give more information and pictures of weeds/ground, the https://gardening.stackexchange.com/   can maybe help more.

2a. smooth uneveness ... 2b. add topsoil

Thank you. I used concentrated glyphosate a few months ago but Im going to use a vinegar mix this time around

Your steps are in a reasonable order, but you don't need to aerate recently tilled soil. That's not productive. To the contrary, consider compacting the soil slightly with a plate device to reduce settling later, which causes waviness. Even mildly compacted you can easily rake your seed into the surface.
You may not need additional topsoil. Once you've tilled adequately you should be able to level the soil to a satisfactory degree. Only bring in soil if you need to raise grade or bolster poor quality soil.
Absolutely critical is keeping the soil moist during the first few weeks of growth. If it dries, it dies.

You really need to hire someone if this is your process.
Tilled weed will just show up again
Tilled soil doesn't need to be aerated
Tilled soil can be raked to even it out
Grass seed needs to be in the soil, and needs covering to protect it.
